# AdWords works on one disk but not on the other?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015, google-admin-sdk

Context: Azure; C#; Visual Studio Community 2015; Google.Ads.Common.3.14.0; Google.AdWords.18.26.1

Weirdest thing. I have built a commandline app in C# to list all the budgets of the accounts we administer. The solution files are in E:\Sources\BudgetLister (E: is an Azure drive.) I want to run it from our Azure C: drive (C:\Web\ARC).

It runs perfectly from the project's bin/Debug folder. When I copy the EXE and the relevant DLLs across to C: and launch the EXE everything runs nicely until the first AdWords-specific instructions are encountered. Then I get

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ApplicationException: The SoapListenerExtension class is not loaded. The most possible cause for this error is that you haven't registered Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.SoapListenerExtension as a soap extension under configuration/system.web/webServices/soapExtensionTypes in your your App.config or Web.config. See the sample App.config for details on how to register soap extensions.
   at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.AdsSoapClient.InitForCall(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Lib.AdWordsSoapClient.InitForCall(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.AdsSoapClient.MakeApiCall(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.AdsSoapClient.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.v201603.ManagedCustomerService.get(Selector serviceSelector)
   at BudgetLister.Program.getHierarchy(AdWordsUser user) in E:\Sources\BudgetLister\BudgetLister\Program.cs:line 410
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at BudgetLister.Program.getHierarchy(AdWordsUser user) in E:\Sources\BudgetLister\BudgetLister\Program.cs:line 458
   at BudgetLister.Program.doListDB(AdWordsUser user, String billingId, String since, Config cfg) in E:\Sources\BudgetLister\BudgetLister\Program.cs:line 237
   at BudgetLister.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\Sources\BudgetLister\BudgetLister\Program.cs:line 134
```

Now I know for sure that I have `registered Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.SoapListenerExtension as a soap extension under configuration/system.web/webServices/soapExtensionTypes in your your App.config` 'cause I can see it in the App.config file in the IDE. And besides it wouldn't work when launched from the E: drive if I hadn't. So why doesn't it work on C:?